# How to allow encoded slashes for websockets in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

Is there a way to enable encoded slashes for websockets in tomcat?
I have set `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH` to `true` and it works as expected for web requests.
Hovewer, there is a problem with WS requests. That setting doesn't seem to work for them.

I have WS endpoint configured as like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/data/{path}", decoders = ChatMessageDecoder.class, encoders = ChatMessageEncoder.class)
```

It works just fine for URL `ws://localhost:8080/app/ws/data/Test` but it doesn't work for URL `ws://localhost:8080/ws/data/Test%2FSubDir`. For the latter URL I receive 404 error.

Is there a way to allow encoded slashes for WS requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make encoding working, but I have 3 alternative solutions.

1. Make multiple `@ServerEndpoint`:

   ```
   @ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/data/{path}"
   public SingleChatHandler : ChatHandler {
       @OnOpen
       public void onOpen(
           Session session,
           @PathParam("path") String path) {
           onOpenInternal(session, path);
       }
   }
   @ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/data/{path1}/{path2}"
   public DoubleChatHandler : ChatHandler {
       @OnOpen
       public void onOpen(
           Session session,
           @PathParam("path1") String path1,
           @PathParam("path2") String path2) {
           onOpenInternal(session, path1 + '/' + path2);
       }
   }
   public abstract class ChatHandler {
       protected void onOpenInternal(Session session, String path) { [...] }
   }
   ```

   This however has two main disadvantages:

   - depth of the path must be know beforehand to implement required handlers
   - there is no way to have more than one parameter with slashes
2. Use query string instead of `@PathParam`:

   ```
   @ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/data")
   public class ChatHandler {
       @OnOpen
       public void onOpen(Session session) {
           Map<String, List<String>> map = session.getRequestParameterMap();
           if (!map.containsKey("path")) {
               // TODO: throw exception
           }
           String path = map.get("path").get(0);
       }
   }
   ```

   This has 2 disadvantages as well, but less troublesome:

   - URL is not too nice
   - there will be no 404 when parameters are not provided (I still see 101)
3. Use query string instead of `@PathParam` (use code from 2. as a base) and check query string in `modifyHandshake` method:

   ```
   public class ChatHandlerConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator
   {
       @Override
       public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response)
       {
           Map<String, List<String>> map = request.getParameterMap();
           if (!map.containsKey("path")) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("path was not provided");
           }

           // Optionally add values to userProperties
           Map<String, Object> userProperties = config.getUserProperties();
           userProperties.put("path", map.get("path").get(0));
       }
   }
   ```

   This behaves similarly to 2. but since I throw exception on handshake, instead of 101 there will be 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are ignoring the **@PathParam**.

I tried the following code and works as expected without any additional configuration:

```
package com.logicbig.example;

import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;

@ServerEndpoint("/hello/{parameter}")
public class HelloWorldEndpointWilcard {

    public HelloWorldEndpointWilcard() {
        System.out.println("class loaded " + this.getClass());
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("parameter") String parameter) {
        System.out.printf("Session opened, id: %s%n", session.getId());
        System.out.println("parameter onOpen:"+parameter);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hi there, we are successfully connected.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session, @PathParam("parameter") String parameter) {
        System.out.printf("Message received. Session id: %s Message: %s%n",
                session.getId(), message);
        System.out.println("parameter onMessage:"+parameter);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(String.format("We received your message: %s%n", message));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.printf("Session closed with id: %s%n", session.getId());
    }
}
```

And this javascript client:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/example/hello/Test%2FSubDir");
```

**Test%2FSubDir** value was received successfully on session established and on each message:

[image: log]

> Complete java source code [here](https://github.com/jrichardsz/web-sockets-template)

Comment: This still doesn't work for me, so question arises - which version of Tomcat did you use?